# PHP preg_match() or strpos to check if string starts with substring

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am changing views of a page depending the `$_GET['code']` it can equal a series of different codes but they will all start with either `Red`, `Town` or `Bearing`, then a series of characters.

For example, the following would all trigger the condition

```
RedWings-223123-NY
Townmansion-2341322-KY
BearingWays-23422-DC
```

I have tried

```
<?php if(preg_match("%(?=.*Bear)(?=.*Red)(?=.*Town)%", $_GET['code'])): ?>

   <span> new view </span>

<?php endif ?>
```

and

```
<?php if( strpos($_GET['code']), "Red" ) !== false) || strpos($_GET['code']), "Bear" ) !== false || strpos($_GET['code']), "Town" ) !== false)): ?>

   <span>new view</span>

<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: And none of them work? What is the value of `$_GET['code']` , make sure it's what you expect it to be

Comment: Your regex implies that they should all be matched. You should use `(?=.*(?:Bear|Town|Red))` instead. But honestly, `^(?:Bear|Town|Red)` performs **much** better than using positive lookaheads

Comment: Good catch chris. And the regex doesn't seem correct either. But this may work: https://regex101.com/r/56Gh34/1

Comment: @chris85  thanks for that. It didn't solve my issue.

Comment: @Andreas awesome tool thanks it give a great explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `strpos` is incorrect syntactically, you close the functions before passing the term to search for.

Your regex requires all terms be present and doesn't check for the start of the string. You need to use an `or` and a leading anchor. This:

```
^(?:Bear|Town|Red)
```

should do it.

Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/civdig/3/

Correct `strpos` usage:

```
<?php if( strpos($_GET['code'], "Red" ) === 0 || strpos($_GET['code'], "Bear" ) === 0 || strpos($_GET['code'], "Town" === 0)): ?>

   <span>new view</span>

<?php endif ?>
```

You need the `0` to confirm it matches, otherwise you are checking that it is somewhere in there.

Comment: `^(?:Bear|Town|Red)` performs much better (the user simply needs to confirm a match)

Comment: That's true, but anchor reduces number of steps to 30 (from 173)

Comment: User specified: *they will all start with either `Red`, `Town` or `Bearing`*, so I'm assuming they all start with those words.

Comment: @chris85 could you verify the " ^ " is to signify starts with, the " ? " is that is optional, the " : " is that the following could be and finally the " | " are or operators.

Comment: `?:` is a non capture group, the `()` creates a capture group without it which isn't needed. The () is needed because otherwise the `^` will only affect the first term. This would be the same, `^Bear|^Town|^Red`.